# .net Entity Framework T4 template does not build/work after upgrade to VS 2012

Tags: entity-framework, build, visual-studio-2012, t4

After installing Vs 2012, I am trying to add a Entity model database first.
How ever the T4 Template will not build.

I am getting these errors when I try to debug it.

> Error 1 - There was a problem loading the assembly
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
>   The following Exception was thrown: System.BadImageFormatException:
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format. File name:
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
>   AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.AttemptAssemblyLoad(String
>   assemblyName)
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = MANNVIT\Ole LOG: Where-ref bind. Location =
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0/Common7/IDE/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context. WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be
>   probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load(). LOG: No
>   application configuration file found. LOG: Using host configuration
>   file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
>   terminated.
>
> Warning   2   Compiling transformation: The predefined type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' is defined in
>   multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'    C:\Users\Ole\documents\visual
>   studio 11\Projects\Cantina\Cantina\Models\navision.Context.tt
>
> Error 3   Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'CSharp'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)  c:\Users\Ole\AppData\Local\Temp\qiu0vq02.0.cs
>
> Error 4   Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name
>   'CSharpCodeProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework
>   Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude  37  22
>
> Error 5   Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name
>   'CompilerErrorCollection' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.CodeDom.Compiler' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude

I believe that the problem is the mixture of 32 bit and 64 bit dlls that it is trying to use.

Loading 64 bit mscorlib.dll and 32 bit system.data.dll. (But I am not sure)

My build configurator platform is any CPU.

Tried putting in `<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>` in my C# project file but that did not help.

I am using a 64 bit win 7 pc. I have also vs 2010 installed.

I have done the the following, installed vs 2012 prof. rtm, uninstalled vs 2012 ultimate rc.

After this I noticed the error.

Then I tried uninstalling all .net frameworks and vs 2012 rtm.  And installin vs 2012 rtm again, but it still gives me the error.

Can someone pls. help me in what is wrong.

Comment: Could you add more information about your environment. Do you have both VS 2010 and VS 2012 installed? Did you uninstall VS 2010 before/after installing VS 2012?

Comment: I have updated my post with more information about my invironment

Comment: My company is having the same problem.  We have 2010 & 2012 VStudio Ultimate installed side by side.  2010 was installed first.  In our case we have Windows 8 installed.

Comment: This problem is still haunting me, does anyone have a suggestion for a solution to this problem ?... I have updated vs 2012 to update 1 and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakenly set the build configuration to x64, and got the same error.  When I put it to Any CPU the error went away.  When I put it back to x64, it still built OK.  So I don't know why, but changing the build configuration and changing it back fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a newline at the end of your T4 file.

I recently saw the same error as a result of a change in our newline settings for our version control system. It appears that the lack of a newline at the end of a text template causes a missing end brace in the compiled template code - which creates a cascading compilation failure that ends with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Visual Studio as administrator ("Run as Administrator" in context menu).